# Hiding empty templates until the data is loaded with Restangular and UI-Router

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router, restangular, oclazyload

I use `ocLazyLoad` to dependency injection and load CSS & JS on-demand. I would not change UI-Router `state` until the data has been loaded. Also I use `Restangular` to connect API.

Now how to call Restangular function from resolve state? It's my route:

```
.state('admin.users',{
    url: "/users",
    templateUrl: "user/views/users.html",
    controller:'UserListCtrl',
    resolve: {
        dep: ['$ocLazyLoad',
            function( $ocLazyLoad ){
                return $ocLazyLoad.load(['UserService.js']).then(
                    function(){
                        return $ocLazyLoad.load(['UserListCtrl.js']);
                    }
                );
            }],
       resolvedItems: userlist()
    }
})
```

and my `UserListCtrl` is:

```
app.controller('UserListCtrl',function($scope,UserService){  

    /*
     * Get all users
     */
    userlist = function(){
        UserService.list().then(function(data){
             $scope.users = data;
             $scope.pagination = $scope.users.metadata;
             $scope.maxSize = 5;
        });
    }
})
```

and my `UserService` is:

```
angular.module('app').service('UserService', function($rootScope, Restangular) {
    /*
     * Build collection /user
     */
    var _userService = Restangular.all('user');


    /*
     * Get list of users
     */
    this.list = function() {
        // GET /api/user
        return _userService.getList();
    };
})
```

Comment: talking about 'Hiding empty templates' - did you try to use 'ng-cloak' ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot call a function from controller at config components. For waiting backend response for page openening you should use resolve feature of ui-router.

You already defined `resolvedItems` so make your userList request in there and resolve response like this...

```
resolve: {
    dep: ['$ocLazyLoad',
        function( $ocLazyLoad ){
            return $ocLazyLoad.load(['UserService.js']).then(
                function(){
                    return $ocLazyLoad.load(['UserListCtrl.js']);
                }
            );
        }],
   resolvedItems: ['UserService', function(UserService){
            return UserService.list().then(function(response){
                return response;
            })
        }]
}
```

and after it you should inject `resolvedItems` on you controller then page will not be shown until your request is completed...